# Trying to use this command "sudo apt-get update"...but getting GPG error

Tags: gnupg

I am a new user of Ubuntu and trying to install OpenFOAM CFD software on Ubuntu 14.04.5. I entered the command `sudo apt-get update` and got the following error at the end.

```
W: GPG error: http://dl.openfoam.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6C0DAC728B29D817
```

I tried to fix this error by using this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 6C0DAC728B29D817
```

But it did not work and I got this error:

```
gpg: requesting key 8B29D817 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 6C0DAC728B29D817 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the following commands?

```
sudo sh -c "wget -O - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu
```